# Add conditional colors on histogram Plotly R

Tags: colors, plotly, histogram, conditional-formatting

I am encountering a dead end with plotly.
I want to modify an existing histogram to add colors according to the value of the bars, without using `ggplot` and `ggplotly`.

Here is my initial code :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

result <- crossing(
  production  = runif(50, 30, 50),
  prix = runif(50, 20, 40),
  charges = runif(50, 100, 200)
) %>% 
  mutate(
    solde = production * prix - charges)


descript <- tibble(
  moy = mean(result$solde),
  mediane = median(result$solde),
  nb_val = length(result$solde),
  q1 = quantile(result$solde, 0.25),
  q3 = quantile(result$solde, 0.75),
  interv = q3 -q1
)

hist <- hist(result$solde, breaks = 8, freq = FALSE,plot = FALSE)
xlim <- range(hist$breaks)
ylim  <- c(0, ceiling(max(hist$density)*2*10000))   

graph_hist <- plot_ly(data = result) %>%
  add_histogram( 
    x = ~solde,
    alpha = 0.7,
    type = "histogram",
    histnorm = "percent", 
    xbins = list(size = 200), 
    hovertemplate = paste('<i>Solde</i>: ','%{x}',"€",
                          '<br> %{y} % des valeurs')) 

coche_quart <- TRUE

if(coche_quart){
  
  graph_hist <- graph_hist %>% 
    add_lines(x =  descript$q1,
              y = ylim) %>%
    add_lines(x =  descript$mediane, color =I("blue"),
              y = ylim) %>%
    add_lines(x =  descript$q3, color =I("green"),
              y = ylim) %>%
    add_text( x = descript$mediane,
              y = 3,
              text = "Médiane",
              textposition = "right")%>%
    add_text( x = descript$q1,
              y =  3,
              text = "Q1",
              textposition = "right") %>%
    add_text( x = descript$q3,
              y =  3,
              text = "Q3",
              textposition = "right")
  
}
```

Here are my unsuccessful attempts for the fill :

```
coche_confort <- TRUE

if(coche_confort){
  
  col<-case_when(result$solde <  600  ~ "red",
                 result$solde >  900 ~ "green",
                 TRUE ~ "orange"))
  
  style(graph_hist, marker = list(
  color = col) )
  
}
```

And here is the code I had written using ggplotly. However I have interactions between the tooltips and the text.

```
      if(r$coche_confort){
        
        w <- w +
          aes(fill = case_when(solde <  r$s_mini  ~ "A",
                               solde >  r$s_att ~ "B",
                               TRUE ~ "C")) +
          scale_fill_manual(
            values = c("A" = "red",
                       "C" = "orange",
                       "B" = "green3")
          )+
          theme(
            legend.position = "none")
        
        
      } else {
        w <- w +
          aes(fill = "#XXXXX") +
          scale_fill_manual(values = c("#XXXXX" = "#77b5fe"))  +
          theme(
            legend.position = "none")
      }
```

Thank you in advance